# No full page reload when navigating from page A to page B: is this possible with Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, pages

Many websites nowadays don't reload a new page when navigating from one page to another.

Instead, only the part of the page that has changed is updated (AJAX-style), but for example the menu, footer, etc. aren't reloaded. This gives a snappy behaviour when navigating such a website.

**Is this behaviour possible with modern versions of Wordpress?**

It seems that it is not enabled by default: for example https://wordpress.org/ doesn't implement it: when you click in the menu on "Learn > Documentation", you can see that a totally new request is done, and the whole page is refreshed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample site that does what you are describing?

Comment: @rudtek gmail.com when you navigate from Inbox to All mail, to a compose email dialog. Another example: https://vuejs.org/: when you click on top menu "API" or "About > FAQ", the page isn't reloaded.

Comment: Both those are using ajax.  Neither work if I disable JS when browsing (they load as traditional links).  To answer your question, yes, this is possible.  Load the links with Ajax requests and just replace your content div as links are pressed.

Comment: @rudtek Yes, that's the way to go, I have done it when doing a custom website in PHP + JS, etc. My question is: do recent WP versions have an option (in the Settings) to do this automatically, so we don't need to reinvent the wheel by replacing links by AJAX requests?

Comment: Ah, I see.  No.  Vanilla Wordpress doesn't do that.  There may be some plugins though.  Sorry!

Comment: of course it's possible, if that's your question then the answer is "yes" but this isn't something WordPress itself provides, it's something that you write javascript for. Sometimes it's called PJAX, sometimes it's a headless react app, there are thousands of ways and methods of doing this, as well as very good reasons not to do this ( it is not always as snappy as you might believe )

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you, I think your comment gives the answer (feel free to post as answer I'll accept it): `this isn't something WordPress itself provides`. Theoretically, it *could* (WP already includes some JS code after all), it would just be an option in the "Settings" ("replace `a href` links by AJAX requests"). If done properly (I've already done it for custom websites in PHP + JS), it works very well, and I don't see reasons not to use it: it improves the navigation UI/UX. NB: When the browser has no JS enabled, it works normally with normal links.

Comment: it adds weight to the page, it can break accessibility features, it can fail leading to links that don't work, it breaks the stop button in the native browser chrome, it has issues when the network connectivity is poor especially in that inbetween stage where the user has clicked a link but the destination hasn't loaded yet ( some sites put a spinner up and now the user is trapped on a loading page if it the request gets stuck ). GitHub tries to do something similar to this and most of the time it's ok but sometime it isn't (and tests show it's actually slower), etc. It isn't a silver bullet.

Comment: If you want fast snappy pages, you can do that with pre-fetching/caching/having a fast site

Comment: @TomJNowell Is pre-fetching available easily in WP? Pre-fetching, does this mean it would pre-load in memory the HTML for all WP pages linked to, for example, all top-level menu buttons? So when we actually click, it is super fast? Feel free to include this pre-fetch mention in your answer, it's a good idea!

Comment: pre-fetching isn't a WordPress thing, it's a HTML thing, asking in the specific context of WordPress doesn't make sense. It's the same for how you would implement PJAX, it isn't really a WordPress thing in the same way React or CSS aren't WordPress things

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something WordPress provides at the moment, "PJAX" is a general term and technology that has lots of implementations and tradeoffs, similar to how there is no one way to do your CSS.

There is talk of something similar to this with the interactivity API for block themes though, but that's in the highly experimental proposal stages and locks you into a very specific way of doing things (it's not PJAX as you've described it).

Fundamentally, there are literally thousands of ways to do this, there's no one specific method, and it isn't the free meal you think it is.

When it works great it's great, but there are lots of downsides too, a lot of it is perceived snappiness rather than actual speed, and there's no guarantee it will actually be faster. You may also find in addition to accessibility issues that there are fundamental compatibility issues with certain plugins and themes around javascript event handlers and DOM ready handlers that don't fire when you load a new page, or plugins that conditionally register their JS to try and speed things up not working because you started browsing on a page that doesn't use it.

On top of that, the huge variety of ways to do this from small JS snippets to headless applications means the tradeoffs are wide and varied. At a minimum ensure that:

- your solution uses the browser history API, if it does not the URL and the forward/back buttons in the browser will not work as they're supposed to, neither will browser history or sharing
- your solution has timeouts and handles poor network connectivity. E.g. if I click on a link and it takes 10 seconds to load, what happens in those 10 seconds? What should the browser address bar say during that time?

---

And importantly, in a normal page load the browser can progressively render the page piece by piece as it's loaded. This is what most of google page speeds tests are trying to optimise. You throw all of that away by doing this, the DOM sees none of that until the JS has gotten all the HTML and updates it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, sure, it's not free meal, correctly handling the History API is tricky, I already spent time on this, I agree :)

Comment: PS: about your last bullet point: *your solution has timeouts and handles poor network connectivity. E.g. if I click on a link and it takes 10 seconds to load, what happens in those 10 seconds* => this is the same if I click on a "standard" link : if poor connectivity, then the new "page" won't load during 10 second as well.

Comment: if it takes 10 seconds during a normal link then the behaviour is well defined and what a user expects, the problem is changing that in your UI, e.g. a site might change the URL immediatley but not update the UI until the page has loaded, or it might put a spinner in place until it has loaded but then fail and leave the user stuck. The user might also see it's taking a while, hit back, then have the page finish loading and replace the HTML anyway leaving the state de-synced, same if they click several links in quick succession.

Comment: Similarly if the new page 404's/500's the user would see standard browser pages but you'd have to build those from scratch. The primary benefit I see from doing this is the ability to put a loading animation and transition, it isn't actually faster, and you can already pre-fetch pages without this so the browser can do an instant snap to a new page when the user clicks without swapping the HTML out with javascript

Comment: *The primary benefit I see from doing this is the ability to put a loading animation*: IMHO, not really. @TomJNowell The primary benefit is that it's *really* faster (I have done the tests on various websites): with standard websites (e.g. https://wordpress.org), clicking on a top menu link *repaints* the whole page: you can see the toolbar flashing during 150 ms, or more depending on your device. On the other hand, clicking on top menu links of https://vuejs.org/api/ means *no repaint* of the top menu bar. It is a more "seamless" UI/UX. NB: this is more visible on mid-end / low-end devices.